# Wordpress: redirect after login

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I get this code to run a redirection on login.

It works fine if the login is done in the login page: wp-login.php .But my site has a modal window which allows login, and this the code doesn't work. The user is redirected to the "my-account" page.

How can I get this code to work also for the login modal window?

```
function redirect_sw($redirect_to, $request, $user){
    $redirect_to = WP_HOME.'/quote-list/'; 
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'redirect_sw', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: How is created the login modal window? Maybe there is hoooked another filter which creates redirect to my-account page?

Comment: @kybernaut.cz But in this case the priority of the filter should be enough to make my filter to be fired first. Am I right? I tried with other value but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: Not necessarily, if you have no idea how the redirect is done, priority 10 could be more or the redirect is maybe not created the WordPress way... What you use for this modal version? Is that any free plugin, part of the theme? Have a look in the code or look for the settings of the plugin/theme, maybe it's possible to change it there.